# How to format mobile number with Persian numerals in Swift?

Tags: swift

I use this extension to create mobile format in text Field, but it does not work in Persian numbers [۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹]

```
   extension String{
    func applyPatternOnNumbers(pattern: String) -> String {
        let  replacmentCharacter: Character = "#"
        var pureNumber = self.replacingOccurrences( of: "[^0-9]", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
        for index in 0 ..< pattern.count {
            guard index < pureNumber.count else { return pureNumber }
            let stringIndex = String.Index(encodedOffset: index)
            let patternCharacter = pattern[stringIndex]
            guard patternCharacter != replacmentCharacter else { continue }
            pureNumber.insert(patternCharacter, at: stringIndex)
        }
        return pureNumber
     }
}
```

to use

```
let mobile = "+18004449999"
let pattern = "+# (###) ###-####"
textfield.text = mobile.applyPatternOnNumbers(pattern: pattern)
// result +1 (800) 4444-9999
```

Comment: Unrelated per se: `۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹` are Arabic-Indic numerals, or Persian numerals, mainly used in Iran (not an Arab country). `0123456789` are the [Arabic numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_numerals). The [Hindu-Arabic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu%E2%80%93Arabic_numeral_system) numerals `٩ ٨ ٧ ٦ ٥ ٤ ٣ ٢ ١ ٠`are used in some but not all arab countries.

Comment: Those numerals are in Persian. Arabic has `٦` but `۶` is Persian numeral for `6`.

Comment: You should not rewrite your question to completely different thing than the original. This `applyPatternOnNumbers` may not fit for your _editingChanged event_ handler, but that is far from your original question _How to format mobile number with Persian numerals_. I strongly recommend you to revert this question to the former one and start a new thread.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55783786/how-to-format-mobile-number-in-swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right regex pattern would be `[^۰-۹0-9]`, but your usage of `String.Index.init(encodedOffset:)` is wrong. (Many programmers use it wrongly, so it is deprecated in Swift 5.)

I have rewritten your extension a little more to make it work with Swift 5 and later:

```
extension String{
    func applyPatternOnNumbers(pattern: String) -> String {
        let replacmentCharacter: Character = "#"
        let pureNumber = self.replacingOccurrences( of: "[^۰-۹0-9]", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
        var result = ""
        var pureNumberIndex = pureNumber.startIndex
        for patternCharacter in pattern {
            if patternCharacter == replacmentCharacter {
                guard pureNumberIndex < pureNumber.endIndex else { return result }
                result.append(pureNumber[pureNumberIndex])
                pureNumber.formIndex(after: &pureNumberIndex)
            } else {
                result.append(patternCharacter)
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Examples:

```
do {
    let mobile = "+18004449999"
    let pattern = "+# (###) ###-####"
    let result = mobile.applyPatternOnNumbers(pattern: pattern)
    print("result \(result)") //->result +1 (800) 444-9999
}
do {
    let mobile = "+۰۹۸۹۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹"
    let pattern = "+## (###) ###-####"
    let result = mobile.applyPatternOnNumbers(pattern: pattern)
    print("result \(result)") //->result +۰۹ (۸۹۱) ۲۳۴-۵۶۷۸
}
```

Please try.

Comment: There is a problem in editing the textField, the numbers can be remove, but the space and  - , ( ,  ),  is not remove

Comment: @amin, sorry but it's quite unclear what is the problem. Please provide, -- input data, -- expected result, and -- actual result.

Comment: i used applyMobileFormat() in textField on .editingChanged event, when typed apply pattern exactly, but When the character wants to delete, only the numbers are deleted

Comment: @amin, Maybe you are misusing this extension in your event handler. Better start a new thread including the code of the handler, unless you have found some flaws in this answer itself.

Comment: Please apply pattern on a text field in editingChanged, 
Type and delete numbers to see the result and problem

Answer (score 0):

That's because of:

```
var pureNumber = self.replacingOccurrences( of: "[^0-9]", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
```

`[^0-9]` should be `[^۰-۹] | [^0-9]`:

```
var pureNumber = self.replacingOccurrences( of: "[^۰-۹] | [^0-9]", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
```

Thus:

```
let mobile = "+۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹۹"
let pattern = "+# (###) ###-####"
let result = mobile.applyPatternOnNumbers(pattern: pattern)
print(result) // ++ (۰۱۲) ۳۴۵-۶۷۸۹۹
```

Comment: The result broke up, both for English and Persian +++ (+ () + (-) + (-) +

Comment: @amin could you please explain?

Comment: I changed pureNumber to [^۰-۹] | [^0-9] but result completely is broke up And the result shows like this +++ (+ () + (-) + (-) +

Comment: editted question with an example of input string and requirement result